# React Native "run-ios" Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, unexpected-token

I am trying to re-install react native. It was working fine, but when I re-installed it it shows some error in building IOS app.

I installed react-native using

> npm install -g react-native-cli

and then created new project

> react-native init GM

It was success, Now the versions are as follows

> ```
> node --version
> v8.11.2
> npm --version
> 5.6.0
> react-native --version
> react-native-cli: 2.0.1
> react-native: 0.55.4
> ```

Then I tried

> react-native run-ios

And it shows the error

```
node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/file.js:63   constructor(options, {
                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/reactNative/GM/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/reactNative/GM/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js:147:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34) Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

I am following the same  step as mentioned in [ReactNative](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to get a better answer.

Comment: Looks like there is a syntax error in a component plz provide the relevant code.

Comment: @supra28 yeah, but its the npm package automatically installed by react-native

Comment: I am having the same issue with `react-native init`.

Comment: I reinstalled Node, NVM and everything, Its working fine now..Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading Node and NPM fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Can you please tell me which version you are using now

Comment: NPM 6.1.0 and Node v8.11.2 now

Comment: let me try that too

Comment: No luck,
npm 6.1.0
node v8.11.2
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55.4

Comment: I reinstalled Node, NVM and everything, Its working fine now..Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Just a note, Xcode uses your default system version.  Using "nvm ls" will tell you which versions are installed and which is the system default.  This is important b/c I had the newest version installed but it wasn't the system default so Xcode was giving the error even though my terminal showed correct version.